# Help fixing trigger/class for Campaign lookup fields

Tags: apex, trigger, contact, campaign, campaign-member

I have a couple of custom Campaign lookup fields on the Contact object called First Campaign and Most Recent Campaign.

These lookup fields need to get populated with the ID of the appropriate Campaign (should be pretty self explanatory-First Campaign would lookup to the first Campaign that the Contact was added to, Most Recent Campaign would lookup to the most recent Campaign that the Contact was added to).

This action is supposed to take place when either of a couple of other custom Date/Time fields (Most Recent PQC Date/Most Recent Upsell PQC Date) on the Contact are updated.

But when I add my test Contact to a couple of test Campaigns, these fields don't update instantaneously like they should. And when they do update, they often are populated incorrectly (values in First Campaign and Most Recent Campaign are often the same, even if the Contact has been added to more than 1 campaign).

I would really appreciate help figuring out why the code isn't working as intended and what the fix is. Here is the trigger:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact ( after update) {

    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isafter && RecursionClass.fireContactUpdate)
    {
        ContactTriggerHandler hndl = new ContactTriggerHandler ();  
        hndl.UpdateContact(trigger.OldMap ,trigger.NewMap);
    }
}
```

Here is the handler class:

```
public class ContactTriggerHandler {
    ContactTriggerAction act = new ContactTriggerAction();
    public void UpdateContact(Map<id ,Contact> OldMap , Map<id , Contact> NewMap)
    {
        act.UpdateContactCampaignField(OldMap,NewMap);
    }
}
```

Here is the class that performs the action:

```
public class ContactTriggerAction {

    //METHOD TO SET CAMPAIGN NAME ON CONTACT IF PQC DATE FIELDS ARE UPDATED
    public void UpdateContactCampaignField(Map<id ,Contact> oldMap , Map<id , Contact> newMap)
    {
        List<Id> filteredContactIds = new List<Id>();

        //check for fields if updated
        for(Contact newCon :newMap.values())
        {
           Contact oldCon = oldMap.get(newCon.id);

           system.debug('___newCon__ContactStatus__c___'+newCon.ContactStatus__c);

           //FILTER CONTACTS WHOSE MostRecentPQCDate OR MostRecentUpsellPQCDate IS UPDATED 

           if( (newCon.MostRecentMQCDate__c!=null && oldCon.MostRecentMQCDate__c != newCon.MostRecentMQCDate__c) || (newCon.MostRecentUpsellMQCDate__c !=null && oldCon.MostRecentUpsellMQCDate__c!= newCon.MostRecentUpsellMQCDate__c) )
               filteredContactIds.add(newCon.Id);
        }

        system.debug('___filteredContactIds____'+filteredContactIds+'__current__userId___'+UserInfo.getUserId());

        //Functionality doesn't run if trigger is fired by integration user to avoid assignment issues
        if(filteredContactIds!=null && filteredContactIds.size()>0 && UserInfo.getUserId() != System.Label.Integration_User_Id)
            CheckRecentCampaignmembers(filteredContactIds);        
    }

    //METHOD TO SET RECENT CAMPAIGN AND FRIST CAMPAIGN ON CONTACT 
    @future
    public static void CheckRecentCampaignmembers(List<Id> contactIdLst)
    {

        system.debug('___entered____CheckRecentCampaignmembers____');

        List<Contact> cLstToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

        //SETTING MostRecentCampaign AND FirstCampaign FIELDS OF CONTACT WITH LastModified CAMPAIGNID
        //FETCH CAMPAIGN MEMBER RECORDS TO WHICH CONTACT IS LINKED 
        for(Contact cont : [Select Id, Name, FirstCampaign__c, MostRecentCampaign__c ,(Select Id, CampaignId , HasResponded from CampaignMembers where HasResponded=TRUE ORDER BY LastModifiedDate desc limit 1) from Contact where Id In :contactIdLst])
        {    

            Contact con_update = new Contact(Id = cont.Id);

           // system.debug('______cont_____'+cont+'____size____'+cont.CampaignMembers.size()+'___campaignId____'+cont.CampaignMembers[0].CampaignId);

            //UPDATING MostRecentCampaign AND FirstCampaign FIELDS ON CONTACT WITH CAMPAIGN NAME
            if(cont.CampaignMembers.size()>0){

                con_update.MostRecentCampaign__c  = cont.CampaignMembers[0].CampaignId;

                //CHECKS IF FIRST CAMPAIGN FIELD IS BLANK
                if(cont.FirstCampaign__c == null)
                {
                    con_update.FirstCampaign__c = cont.CampaignMembers[0].CampaignId;  
                }
            }

            system.debug('____con_update_____'+con_update);

            cLstToUpdate.add(con_update);

        }

        if(cLstToUpdate!=null && cLstToUpdate.size()>0){
            RecursionClass.fireContactUpdate = false;
            update cLstToUpdate ;

        }
    }

}
```

And here is the recursion class:

```
Public class RecursionClass{

    public static Boolean fireContactUpdate = true;
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? What are the problems or logic errors?

Comment: Please edit your original post to explain what is not working or what errors you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, just edited the post. Let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I add my test Contact to a couple of test Campaigns, these fields don't update instantaneously like they should

The way your code is written, this is always going to be the case, because you're performing the Contact update via an `@future` method.

```
@future
public static void CheckRecentCampaignmembers(List<Id> contactIdLst)
```

This method is enqueued by your trigger and will be processed by the server at some unspecified time in the future. (It could be a while, if you're operating under heavy load). If you want the update to be instantaneous, you need to execute it synchronously in your trigger handler class - you already have a guard against recursion here, although you need to reset `fireContactUpdate` to `true` *after* you invoke the recursive `update` DML.

The fact that this update runs in a future method can mean that by the time the method's executed, the actual data state of the Contacts has changed. This makes it more difficult to reason about the code's behavior.

> when they do update, they often are populated incorrectly (values in First Campaign and Most Recent Campaign are often the same, even if the Contact has been added to more than 1 campaign).

Your code only looks at the last Campaign at the time the future method runs:

```
Select Id, Name, FirstCampaign__c, MostRecentCampaign__c ,
    (Select Id, CampaignId , HasResponded 
     from CampaignMembers 
     where HasResponded=TRUE 
     ORDER BY LastModifiedDate desc 
     limit 1) 
from Contact
where Id In :contactIdLst
```

If, when the future method is ultimately executed, more than one Campaign is present, you'll obtain incorrect results.

Further, it's not clear how your fields

> Recent PQC Date/Most Recent Upsell PQC Date

are being populated. I would guess that it's another trigger doing so, but I don't know. Since you cannot guarantee the order of execution between multiple triggers, there could be a variety of different issues here leading to unexpected behaviors.

Typically I would expect this kind of functionality to be implemented in a trigger on Campaign Member, not Contact.

Comment: Hey David-thanks for the input here. I removed the @future method and updated fireContactUpdate to true, which seems to have addressed the issue I was having. Really appreciate the help on this!